# matching content in a specific html tag

Tags: html, regex

I want to match content inside every font tag with a color:

```
inside html <font color="#000000">this should be matched</font><font color="#777777">this shouldn't be</font><font color="#000000">this should be matched too</font> inside html
```

But when I use the following regex:

```
<font color=\"#000000\">(.*)<\/font>
```

It will match the whole string starting with first font tag, including the one that has #77777 color. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML4 and has been removed in HTML5. Consider replacing with CSS :)

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/674700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(.*) matches **everything**, including other  elements. It's in a greedy mode, meaning it will try to consume as much as possible. 
You can add a non-greedy operator to the '*' star operator, usually using *.*?*

Try with :

```
<font color=\"#000000\">(.*?)<\/font>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a 'non-greedy operator', i.e.:

```
<font color=\"#000000\">(.*?)<\/font>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<font>` and `<basefont>` tags should be avoided because they have been deprecated since HTML version 4. Fonts should be provided using CSS rather than the `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<font color=\"#000000\">([^<>]+)<\/font>
```